# ios 8 MapKit location will not start

Tags: ios, mapkit

Since ios 8 I cannot get the mapkit to start in the debugger. I'm using XCode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)
on Mac OS X 10.9.5. And yes I've read and googled several suggestions but I can't get it to work.

I have added these lines in my myproject-info.plist;

```
</array>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>I need location</string>
</dict>
```

This is how I try to initialice LocationManager in my first view viewDidLoad method;

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Later, in another controller i programatically add a mapkit view like this;

```
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];

[mapView setDelegate:self];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

But I always get this in the output console;

*2014-11-22 19:14:36.777 vind4r[1019:16660] Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.*

Any ideas someone?

Kind regards,
Jan Gifvars
Stockholm

Answer (score 0):

Try to move

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

To the 
`-locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:`

There you can check status for >= kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized and set `showsUserLocation` there:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status >= kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've trie your suggestion. Almost there now, i.e. I can see the dialog asking Allow/Don't Allow. But the dialog disappears as soon as my controller has returned from the viewDidLoad method and view renders, Hhhmm, why isn't the dialog modal or what? I never end up in the ... didChangeAuthorizationStatus: method.

Comment: Sorry, i messed up with a local declared locationmanager. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager
```

in your .h file